# GH actions is changing my merge branch from <branchName> to <refs/heads/branchName>

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I am seeing a really bizarre thing happen where seemingly out of nowhere GH actions is recognizing the merge of my feature branch into our staging branch as its refs/heads alias, thus breaking environment protection rules.

Repro:

```
git pull origin <branchName> locally
git branch -b <feature/featureBranchName>

git push origin <feature/featureBranchName>

pr <feature/featureBranchName> in <branchName>
```

gh action fails with the below error:

```
Branch <feature/featureBranchName> is not allowed to deploy to <branchName> due to environment protection rules.
```

Anyone know what is going on or how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This was a defect confirmed by GH in result of a feature release. They have since rolled it back...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).